# list/array element access in couchbase

Tags: node.js, couchbase

Is it possible to store an array

```
var a=[
{"id":"1", "value":null},
{"id":"2", "value":null},
{"id":"3", "value":null},
{"id":"4", "value":null},
{"id":"5", "value":null}
];
```

in a couchbase membase with a document id

if sure, is there a way to get one element, such as

```
 {"id":"2", "value":null}
```

and add/remove one element,such as

```
 {"id":"6", "value":null}
```

?

your comment welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to store an array

Yes, you just need to serialize it

> and add/remove one element

No, you will need to request all document by id, deserialize it's to array, remove element, serialize array and update document.

Comment: what about query to get {"id":"2", "value":null}

Comment: no, you can request only full array. why not to write only elements of array to couchbase instead of full array?

Comment: I hope you understand, that you id in element, and document id is't same things?:)

Answer (score 0):

As alternative instead of using JSON, a binary format could be used instead. Which will allow the use of the append operation. In this case for a delete you could append with the id prefixed with a minus sign.

For example the data could look like this:

```
id:"1",value:"null"
id:"2",value:"null"
-id:"1"
```

At some point you will have to grab the whole document and "clean" it up to stop it growing unbounded. If a delete operation is the unlikely case then it might be worth grabbing the whole document and deleting the id instead of appending with the minus.

Befits

- Reduces the network bandwidth as their is no need to get the whole document
- No need to worries about CAS or locks if the order does not matter

Costs

- View will be harder to use
- Have to create a custom serialiser
- Will need to manage the document to stop it growing unbounded.

The befits only outweigh the costs when working on very large objects.